6.7 returns hr = E_INVALIDARGS while 6.6 and under returns hr = S_OK
6.7 returns hr = E_INVALIDARGS while 6.6 and under returns hr = S_OK.  Any ideas?  I'm guessing my solid state HP Intel HD630 driver is out of date and I am unable to install the latest driver that would have 6.7.
m_shaderModel.HighestShaderModel = D3D_SHADER_MODEL::D3D_SHADER_MODEL_6_7;
//m_shaderModel.HighestShaderModel = D3D_SHADER_MODEL::D3D_SHADER_MODEL_5_1;

HRESULT hr = m_device->m_device->CheckFeatureSupport(
    D3D12_FEATURE::D3D12_FEATURE_SHADER_MODEL,
    &m_shaderModel,
    sizeof(D3D12_FEATURE_DATA_SHADER_MODEL));


System Information
  Time of this report: 12/25/2024, 20:50:29
         Machine name: HP-PAVILION
     Operating System: Windows 10 Home 64-bit (10.0, Build 19045) (19041.vb_release.191206-1406)
             Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
  System Manufacturer: HP
         System Model: HP Pavilion Desktop PC 570-p0xx
                 BIOS: F.46 (type: UEFI)
            Processor: n/a
               Memory: 8192MB RAM
  Available OS Memory: 8072MB RAM
            Page File: 9121MB used, 2890MB available
          Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
      DirectX Version: DirectX 12
  DX Setup Parameters: Not found
     User DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
   System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
      DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
             Miracast: Available, with HDCP
Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Not Supported
DirectX Database Version: 1.0.8
DxDiag Version: 10.00.19041.5198 64bit Unicode


What version of the DirectX 12 Runtime are you using? This would depend on which DirectX 12 Agility SDK you are using or the full OS version you are running. Officially Shader Model 6.7 isn't supported until DirectX 12 Agility SDK 1.606.3 or later

If the DirectX 12 Runtime is returning E_INVALIDARGS that means it doesn't understand Shader Model 6.7 exists.
Support for Shader Model 6.7 in the DirectX12 Runtime was made available officially in the DirectX12 Agility SDK release v1.606.3 per this blog post.
If you are not using the DirectX 12 Agility SDK, then you need to be using Windows 11, Version 24H2 for the DirectX 12 Runtime to support Shader Model 6.7.

The D3D_SHADER_MODEL_6_7 value first showed up in Windows 10 SDK (20279), but that would require enabling experimental features using D3D12ExperimentalShaderModels.


Since HLSL compiler development is open source on GitHub, the new shader model values will show up before they are fully implemented and supported. For example, D3D_SHADER_MODEL_6_8 is defined, but is not yet available.

